# Why w3.css Side navbar is not working on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am new to web page. I am trying to apply side nav bar using **w3css file**. But It doesn't work.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

            <button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>

            <script>
                function w3_open() {
                    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
                }
                function w3_close() {
                    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
                }
            </script>
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CodeBuild</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </nav>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px;" id="mySidebar">
        <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hi this is test page</h1>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> It shows the toggle button when screen size become small. But when I click the button, it refresh the entire page. Not showing the side navbar.I already have bootstrap fixed navbar. Now I want to add side navbar using w3css file. What I did wrong in my code

This is that link from where I takes the code [link](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar_hide&stacked=h)

Comment: @Michaelcoker Bootstrap 3.3.7 and w3css version 4

Comment: No body knows the answer for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `type="button"` or `return false` to your buttons.

**`type="button"`**

```
<button type="button" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>
```

**`return false`**

```
<button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open(); return false">&#9776;</button>
```

If you don't do so, the buttons will be by default `type="submit"` and force the refresh of the page.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebsite.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

            <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>

            <script>
                function w3_open() {
                    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
                }
                function w3_close() {
                    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
                }
            </script>
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CodeBuild</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </nav>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px;" id="mySidebar">
        <button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hi this is test page</h1>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```